# Write with monad bind function

Tags: haskell

I have following function, that is written with `do` statement:

```
  l2 :: Monad m => (a -> b -> c) -> m a -> m b -> m c
  l2 f a b = do
    x <- a
    y <- b
    return (f x y)
```

the `do` statement is the sugar of `>>=`, so I try to write it with operator:

```
  l2' :: Monad m => (a -> b -> c) -> m a -> m b -> m c
  l2' f a b = a >>= (\x -> b >>= (\y -> f x y))
```

and the compiler complains:

```
D:\haskell\chapter18\src\ExerciseMonad.hs:159:41: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `m c' with actual type `c'
      `c' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          l2' :: forall (m :: * -> *) a b c.
                 Monad m =>
                 (a -> b -> c) -> m a -> m b -> m c
        at D:\haskell\chapter18\src\ExerciseMonad.hs:158:10
    * In the expression: f x y
      In the second argument of `(>>=)', namely `(\ y -> f x y)'
      In the expression: b >>= (\ y -> f x y)
    * Relevant bindings include
        b :: m b
          (bound at D:\haskell\chapter18\src\ExerciseMonad.hs:159:11)
        a :: m a (bound at D:\haskell\chapter18\src\ExerciseMonad.hs:159:9)
        f :: a -> b -> c
          (bound at D:\haskell\chapter18\src\ExerciseMonad.hs:159:7)
        l2' :: (a -> b -> c) -> m a -> m b -> m c
          (bound at D:\haskell\chapter18\src\ExerciseMonad.hs:159:3)
```

because the return value of `f` is not in monadic structure. How to improve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to add `return` around `f x y`. Let us have a look how to desugar `do`:

```
do                   --
  x <- foo           -- foo >>= (\x ->
  bar                --   bar >> 
  foobar x           --     foobar x)
```

Note that we didn't remove anything. We just switched the arrows and added `bind`, if you want to read it like that. If we follow that approach, we can desugar your code equivalently:

```
do                   --  
  x <- a             --  a >>= (\x ->
  y <- b             --    b >>= (\y ->
  return (f x y)     --      return (f x y)))
```

The `return` stays. It's not part of `do`'s sugar. We therefore end up with

```
l2' f a b = a >>= (\x -> b >>= (\y -> return (f x y)))
```

Remark: You don't need `Monad` to implement `l2'`, as long as your instance follow the monad and applicative laws. You can use `Applicative` instead:

```
l2' f a b = f <$> a <*> b
```

<sub>Exercise: if you don't know `Applicative` yet, try to guess what `<$>` and `<*>` types might be (in the context of `Monad`).</sub>

Comment: `<$>` is `fmap` in functor and  `<*>` is a function defined in applicative class. The code `l2' f a b = f <$> a <*> b` does , apply `fmap` to `a`, get function `(a->b)` back in context and apply it to value of b with `<*>` apply